# Drupal Taxonomy View as main site navigation

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have searched and tried everything to try and get this working but am still stuck.

I am writing a classified ads site for my local ice rink and can't fo the life of me get the taxonomy structure working. Drupal 7.41

I have a taxonomy structured like this but bigger 
Taxonomy vocabulary name-Skate Catagory
Structure

- Figure Skating

  - skates

    - skate type 1
    - skate type 2
  - bag

    - bag type
  - Clothing
- ice Hockey

  - skates

    - skate type 1
    - skate type 2
  - bag

    - bag type

You get the idea.

I would like a veiw to be the main page that displays the top level terms with an image for each.

When the user clicks the image it drills down to layer 2, so user clicks figure skating and the page changes to show all teasers of figure skating

To drill down further i think quick tabs may be used

Any advice welcome, is this the best way to deal with a 3 level search?